# Properties declared as instance variables too?

Tags: objective-c

This code works:

```
    @interface StringStuff : NSObject {

    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *String1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *String2;

    - (NSString *) doSomethingWithStrings;

    @end
```

But I often see:

```
        @interface StringStuff : NSObject {
             NSString *String1;
             NSSTring *String2;    
        }
        @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *String1;
        @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *String2;

        - (NSString *) doSomethingWithStrings;

        @end
```

Is there a reason that properties are often declared as an instance variable as well? Is it just considered good form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Legacy;  it used to be (and still is on 32 bit Mac OS X targeted code) that the ivar declarations were required.  That is no longer true on iOS, the simulator and 64 bit OS X.

Note that it is common to `@synthesize iVar = iVar_;` to prevent accidental direct access where `self.iVar` is really required.